# Why is console noting that I changed my prototype before I do?

Tags: javascript

I am learning about Javascript prototypes and made a Fiddle (http://jsfiddle.net/3MuZa/1/) with this javascript:

```
function Animal(name, sound) {
    this.name = name;
    this.sound = sound;
}

var dog = new Animal("Dog", "Bark");
console.debug(dog.__proto__);

Animal.prototype.makeSound = function() {console.log(this.sound);};
```

Interestingly, ​`console.debug(dog.__proto__);` reveals that `makeSound` is a method of the prototype of the Animal class.

However, I add that method to the prototype in a later line. Why is Console noting that the prototype has a `makeSound` method if the control flow hadn't gotten to it yet in my code?

Comment: Set a break-point on that last line. Execute to that break-point. Inspect the console. You'll see that `makeSound` is not present.

Comment: Thank you! Indeed, setting a breakpoint and examining local variables reveals that the `makeSound` method does not exist.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The console is "live". even if you do log it first, it will reflect later changes.

As far as i know, it behaves like this on objects, functions, arrays. But if you log strings, booleans and numbers, they print what they mean at the time they were logged.

Comment: If you change the `console.debug` to `console.log` it works as expected.

Comment: @JamesMcLaughlin What do you mean by "as expected"? I see no difference between debug and log.

Comment: Thanks, same here. I don't think I see a difference.

Comment: It depends on the console in the developer tools you're using. There's no specification that defines proper behavior of a console.

Comment: Oh, I see, thanks. I was using the Chrome Web Developer Console. I'll keep this in mind in the future - objects, functions, arrays might not be in the state of the control flow when being logged.

Comment: Sorry, I was using Firebug with Firefox 11.